# Visual studio program window delays when launched

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Pretty new to programming here so forgive me if I'm doing something stupid. When I launch my simple beginner programs on visual studio, its a blank screen for about 5 seconds when it is launched. on paper that doesn't seem like a big deal, but these are "hello world" type programs and when i tried learning a few months ago i didn't encounter this problem. I want to know how to fix this, as I am afraid that it will take longer with the large projects that i eventually hope to get into.

EDIT: Ok, I played around with the subsystem and the problem has seemed to go away. I don't exactly know what I did, but the program I was referring to doesn't have the problem anymore

Comment: When you start a program, you can see in the output window, that a lot of Win32 DLLs are loaded. In Debug mode, this may take a considerable time. (Though, 5 seconds sounds long.) Did you try to start your application directly from `cmd` or from Explorer? Does this need so long as well? How about Release build? I'm not sure what else could play a role, e.g. drive nearly ful, anti-virus software (I had some bad experiences in the past), etc. Can you post some minimal code for which you observe this phenomenom?

Comment: @Scheff When i say new I mean like this is my second day. I am unaware to what Win32 DLLs or cmd is. I've used visual studio on my computer before and haven't had this problem, so I don't think that a couple of games that I downloaded would cause this. Also I don't know how to share code because i created my stackoverflow account for this problem because I'm a noob

Comment: Sorry. You mentioned VisualStudio. So, I assume you develop on Windows. The [Win32 API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) is a set of DLLs shipped with the system. It is needed to use any feature of the operating system. (Even if you use C++ standard libraries only and nothing else these are probably depending somehow on Win32 API functions (surely in the case of input/output).)

Comment: With `cmd`, I meant [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). If you make a Console application, it is run with a Console window. In opposition to this, you can start `cmd.exe` (e.g. by pressing [Win][R], typing `cmd`, and clicking [OK] button) manually which opens a Console window with command interpreter. Then you can start your console application from command prompt (probably with ful absolute path of executable). If curious about this, please, research in Web. There should be plenty of explanations about this.

Comment: A last hint: For Windows specific programming questions, I recommend to include `MDSN` into google search term.

Comment: Concerning _Can you post some minimal code for which you observer this phenomenom?_: Please, see the [edit] link (under the tags of your question). You can edit your question and add text or code samples on request. Post code means copy/paste it into the question (and format code with the [{}] button of the inline editor). In general, I recommend to read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - it gives a basic intro on how to use SO (and I see you didn't because you will earn your first badge for this). ;-)

Comment: You need to go shopping for a better anti-malware product.  Most of the flashy stuff is not suitable for use on a programmer's machine that makes executable files appear from seemingly nowhere.  The one included with your OS is plenty good enough.

Comment: Just to reiterate on what @HansPassant said: sometimes your antivirus software blocks newly created executables and blocks the call to these for a considerable time. Try disabling your antivirus program and see if that changes anything.

Comment: aVast is well known to cause this type of issue or worse.

Comment: ***I mean like this is my second day. I am unaware to what Win32 DLLs or cmd is*** In `c++` you sometimes need to understand your OS in a much deeper level than a regular user.